Calculate end date of partition rows using start date of following partition
How to write LEAD function to take value of next record when there is a change in Type.
Source Data
Person    Type     dt_eff
123       ABC      2018-10-23
123       DEF      2018-12-19
124       ABC      2020-01-01
124       ABC      2020-02-15
124       ABC      2020-05-14
124       DEF      2020-10-13
124       FGD      2021-01-15

Expected Output
Person    Type     Start_date   End_Date
123       ABC      2018-10-23   2018-12-19
123       DEF      2018-12-19   NULL
124       ABC      2020-01-01   2020-10-13
124       ABC      2020-02-15   2020-10-13
124       ABC      2020-05-14   2020-10-13
124       DEF      2020-10-13   2021-01-15
124       FGD      2021-01-15   NULL

Below query is giving only next column value but I want the value of the record when there is a change in type.
SELECT Person, Type, dt_eff AS start_date,
    LEAD(dt_eff,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY dt_eff) AS end_Date
FROM Person


so the second table is not the expected Out Put ?

I added expected output in original post. Not sure what table you are referring.  Expected output contains Start_date and End_date

your second table has the result of the query you posted, so why ask when you have already your answer see https://dbfiddle.uk/quXAQHAl

"Below query is giving only next column value but want the value of the record when there is a change in type."   It is not giving the expected output. as you can see the output clearly is not matching with the expected output given in original post

explsin the logic of your wanted result

End date should be taken from lead record only when there is change in type. example: Person 124, Type ABC End date is given as 2020-10-13 (Type = DEF).

You stopped too soon, after obtaining the lead value, you then need to obtain the max value over the Person, Type partition e.g.
with cte as (
  select *
    , lead(dt_eff) over (partition by Person order by Type, dt_eff) dt_eff_lead
  from Person
)
select Person, Type, dt_eff StartDate
  , max(dt_eff_lead) over (partition by Person, Type) EndDate
from cte
order by Person, Type, dt_eff;

Returns as requested:



Person
Type
StartDate
EndDate




123
ABC
2018-10-23
2018-12-19


123
DEF
2018-12-19
null


124
ABC
2020-01-01
2020-10-13


124
ABC
2020-02-15
2020-10-13


124
ABC
2020-05-14
2020-10-13


124
DEF
2020-10-13
2021-01-15


124
FGD
2021-01-15
null



DBFiddle

Not sure who downvoted. Thanks for the quick query.  But this won't work.  You are doing partition by Type.  Person Just order by DT_EFF then in this order we have to check the type change.   Same type can repeat gain, for example you can replace FGD with ABC as well.

@skv this returns the desired results for the data you posted. If you have missed off edge cases (as you suggest) you need to update your question to include edge cases. Normally you would need to ask a new question since I have answered what you originally asked.

Posted new question as you suggested.  Thanks for answering this . https://stackoverflow.com/q/78462997/11842751

Accepted for above question. Also accepted for other post
