Calculate the end date of partition rows using the start date of the following partition
How can I write a CTE in SQL Server to get the End_Date for a given partition of rows, where the partition is by Person & Type, with a new partition starting if the Type changes within a person. End_Date is defined as the Start_Date of the next Type partition within a Person partition. The last partition within a Person will always have a null End_Date.
I previously asked a similar question, which gained an answer, but I had neglected to show the case where the Type might no only change multiple times within a Person, but might also repeat the same Type again. This scenario should also create a new partition as shown in the data below.
For the following source data, records should be sorted by dt_eff for the person.
Source Data
Person    Type     dt_eff
123       ABC      2018-10-23
123       DEF      2018-12-19
124       ABC      2020-01-01
124       ABC      2020-02-15
124       ABC      2020-05-14
124       DEF      2020-10-13  < Note change of Type to DEF
124       ABC      2021-01-15  < Note change of Type back to ABC

Expected Output
Person    Type     Start_Date   End_Date     Partition
123       ABC      2018-10-23   2018-12-19   123:1 < Start_Date from 123:DEF
123       DEF      2018-12-19   NULL         123:2
124       ABC      2020-01-01   2020-10-13   124:1
124       ABC      2020-02-15   2020-10-13   124:1
124       ABC      2020-05-14   2020-10-13   124:1 < Start_Date from 124:DEF
124       DEF      2020-10-13   2021-01-15   124:2< Start_Date from next 124:ABC
124       ABC      2021-01-15   NULL         124:3

Note the Partition column is not a required output, its just added for clarify

you need to make a bit more of an effort in explaining your question, taking the time to explain the logic in words as well as showing the data. And importantly in this case, explaining why the answer to your previous question doesn't provide the results you want. If you do that I can try and re-open the question for you.

I have an answer for you once the question is clarified.

I am not sure what specific details you are looking for. Maybe i should have given more details. But my previous question/post specifically asked for end date when there is change in Type.  If the type is same then you won't take that date.   In your example just change the type FGD     to ABC and rerun again.  it won't give the desired outcome.

OK, only because I was bored and had already created an answer, I have edited your question to make it clear what is being asked. You have to keep in mind you have the entire context for the question in your mind, so everything makes sense to you. But someone else who hasn't been dealing with the problem has no context, and therefore such a brief explanation as you originally had is not enough. In future please make the effort to quote a clear, precise question, covering the required edge cases. Else you will continue to attract the downvotes that this (and your last question) question did.

@Dale K, you are right. I should have added the comments and more rows to make it clearer.  Thanks for editing the question and giving the query.  It is working as expected.

The key takeaway here is that you can't always produce the results you want in a single query... Sometimes you have to take multiple steps. The following approach is the one I use:

Work out logically how the problem might be solved.
Build a query up that produces the logical result.
See if there is an opportunity to simplify the query.

The following produces the results you desire... how is works is explained in the comments.
with cte1 as (
  select *
    -- 1. Find the dt_eff value of the next row, we need this to get the end date
    , lead(dt_eff) over (partition by Person order by dt_eff) dt_eff_lead
    -- Find the Type value of the previous row, we need this to detect a change in type
    , lag(Type, 1, Type) over (partition by Person order by dt_eff) type_lag
  from Person
), cte2 as (
  select Person, Type, dt_eff Start_Date
    , dt_eff_lead
    -- Count the number of Type transitions by comparing this row with the previous row
    -- prior to and including the current row
    -- Each time the count changes gives us a new partition to use in the final result
    , sum(case when Type <> type_lag then 1 else 0 end)
      over (partition by person order by dt_eff asc
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) TypeGroup
  from cte1
)
select Person, Type, Start_Date
  -- Get the maximum dt_eff_lead for a given type partition within a person partition
  , max(dt_eff_lead) over (partition by Person, TypeGroup) End_Date
from cte2
order by Person, Start_Date, Type;

Fiddle (using data from your last question slightly modified)

"Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.":  This issue is only happening if Type is same for the last records.  If Type is different then it is populated correctly.

@skv that's a warning only and not normally a problem.
